# Document generator for Stencil JS

Tags: javascript, documentation, web-component, stenciljs, stencil-component

I'm using Stencil JS to create custom web components. At a point, I came across this requirement to generate documentation for the custom web components created. There are few doc generated that I tried such as typedoc and docsify. Typedoc seems to be a good option, but it generates the static website. In my requirement, I prefer let the user to dynamically change the values of the code and preview it before it is being used. For this, I found CodeMirror. Is there a way to integrate CodeMirror with TypeDoc to let the user to edit live code and see the changes in the web component.

If there's any other plugins or generator which does this job available, please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on something that may help out. At the moment it's a bit experimental, and  more similar to Storybook than a document tool like TypeDoc, though I'll be working more in that direction as well. The components are all web-components built in StencilJS, so the documentation can become part of whatever project is using the components it documents, rather than a separate process.

https://github.com/steveruizok/st-lookbook

[Demo](https://stencil-projects.firebaseapp.com/)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzRan.png)

Comment: looks interesting, I combined both Typedoc and CodeMirror to achieve what I wanted to do and it works fine for now. Thanks for the links, I'll look in to that